# Darlington Amplifier circuit (TIP 120)

Tags: transistors, mosfet, resistance, bias, darlington

[image: dc gain for tip120]

I'm trying to wire a darlington TIP120 just to see if I can get the 1000 hfe dc gain at 100mA like it said on the data sheet. I made the circuit like it appeared in the data sheet, but wasn't successful. I was hoping for as much as 2A of output current. Is anything wrong with the circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. TIP120 is an NPN device. You’ve drawn it as if it was a PNP.
2. The emitter-collector voltage needs to be around 10V, conservatively, to get such a high gain.

High gains are possible with fairly high C-E voltages. The data sheet provides the conditions necessary for specified hFE - at least it’ll mention the VCE needed.